# Updating only the description of an app in google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to just update the description of my app on Google play and no other changes. I made the changes in developers console but the update description never shows up in google play for my app.
Do I have unpublish and republish the app?
Thanks,
-v-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play usually takes 2-24 hours to update app descriptions, title, screenshots etc. Just wait it out.